# Сравнения строк в Ява

Tags: java, android

Пишу андроид приложения. Есть две строки. Одна из базы данных вторая из сети нужно их сравнить (==)
должно быть что то типа этого:

```
if (str1 == str2){
    //code
}
else {
    //code
}
```

конструкция выше вообще не работает. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Посоветую внимательнее читать учебник.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if (str1.equals(str2))............